# what is the difference between the two date time string?

Tags: javascript, date

Test in Chrome DevTool(China standard time):

```
new Date("2013-12-24").toISOString()
```

"2013-12-24T00:00:00.000Z"

```
new Date("2013/12/24").toISOString()
```

and

```
new Date("Dec 24, 2013").toISOString()
```

"2013-12-23T16:00:00.000Z"

what is the diff with these?

Comment: I get `"2013-12-24T00:00:00.000Z"` and `"2013-12-24T05:00:00.000Z"`.

Answer (score 2):

The first one, `2013-12-24`, is being recognized as the first part of an ISO-8601 date string and since it has no time or timezone associated with it, it is parsed as UTC.

The second one is undefined and up to the browser/JS engine to parse as it pleases. In your case, it appears to be parsing it as a US date string, but using your local timezone instead of UTC. You can read more about the stardardized date formats on the [MDN Page for Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

If you can, just stick with the first since it is a standard. The second example might not even work in different locales, but I can't say for sure. If you really need arbitrary Date parsing, you might want to consider using a library, since it is very complicated and not covered by standard JS. Something like [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) maybe?